# Changing fragments is showing last fragment for 1 second

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am changing fragments inside framelayout.This is my main activity layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.impact.ribony">

    <com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dip"
    android:visibility="gone"
    app:pstsIndicatorColor  ="#0B0B16"
    app:pstsShouldExpand="true" />"

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
         /> 
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_below="@+id/tabs">
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Firstly I am showing login fragment then user logins I am hiding framelayout.Because I am using viewpager.If user wants go to settings I am loading settings fragment then I am showing framelayout again.

But I have a problem,you can see it here: http://youtu.be/H6AO7yYusjM

You can see when user goes to settings fragment,firstly login fragment showing for 1 second then settings fragment is loading.How can I prevent this ? (When I try to change fragment always showing last fragment for 1 second not just login fragment)

If user logins successfully I am removing login fragment with following lines:

```
pager.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
tabs.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
FrameLayout layout = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.container);
layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

I am loading login fragment with following code:

```
FrameLayout layout = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.container);
layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
LoginFragment conv = new LoginFragment();
loginObj=LoginFragment.newInstance("asd");
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, loginObj,"LoginFragment");
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
actionBar.hide();
pager.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

I am loading settings fragment with following code:

```
FrameLayout layout=(FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.container);
pager.setVisibility(View.GONE);
tabs.setVisibility(View.GONE);
FragmentManager fragmentManager=getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction=fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
SettingsFragment conv=new SettingsFragment();
SettingsFragment.newInstance(LOGGED_USERNAME);
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container,conv);
fragmentTransaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: the video link is not working. have you solved your issue?